# How to update a Client Web Part / App Part?

Tags: web-part, javascript, sharepoint-addin, app-part, client

When I add a client app part to a page, then make an update to it in Visual Studio (or the app it's attached to) and then redeploy, the client web part disappears wherever it's installed.  So every time I update the client app part I need to go to every page it's installed on and re-add it?  That doesn't make it very useable.

Looks like there are a few posts about adding client web parts via CSOM but is there really no easier way to deal with them in terms of upgrading?

Comment: This is a pain, but should not be an issue in a production environment where you upload app files to the app catalog and deploy them from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your SharePoint App as a provider hosted app and host it in Azure (or where you want), then you can make any changes to the Web Page which is shown in the Client Web Part without SharePoint knowing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior.

Workaround is to add the app part to page using a feature activation event receiver.